# RAD 8 does not recognize that WAS has started

Tags: websphere, ibm-rad

I have recently experienced a new problem using RAD 8.0.2. When I launch a WAS server from within RAD, with or without any apps published to it, WAS will start and will show output in the console. I can even access the server from my web browser. However, RAD never recognizes that WAS has started successfully and after the timeout limit is reached, RAD claims that the server failed to start. I have tried this with WAS 6.1 and 7.0 test environments and WebSphere Portal 6.1 external environment and I always get the same result. Naturally, this makes development extremely difficult and I am anxious to get this fixed. Any help would be greatly appreciated! - John

Comment: I have the same problem with WPS7 and RAD8. I try to modify the RMI and SOAP ports now and hope for the best...

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573166/why-isnt-rad-eclipse-able-to-properly-detect-was-server-startup)

Answer (score 1):

May be an SSL certificate expiration problem, try this

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21514601

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the issue is with RAD 8.0. I had similar issue which is caused by overridden .Metadata properties. Please follow the steps mentioned below.

- Close RAD
- Kill Java and Javaw.exe on the TaskManager which runs in the background to run eclipse/RAD
- Remove the .Metadata properties from the workspace path( Remember when you remove this properties, the workspace settings and the server will be removed from your workspace)
- Open RAD as Administrator, it automatically creates .metadata in your workspace path. But, it would be a default (without the workspace settings).
- Need to update the user libraries in your workspace and add the servers again( The server settings would be still available as the Server profile was never changed). These settings would update your .Metadata on your workspace.

Answer (score 0):

Try toggling the SOAP and RMI option to see if that helps you.

Sometimes it has trouble and it always works if you switch the protocols that RAD uses to connect to Test envionment server.

Also as a sanity check ensure that the port numbers that are specified in the server configuration in RAD is correct. There are chances that an incorrect port number could be a culprit too.

HTH

Manglu

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I've tried using both the RMI and the SOAP connections and then clicking the "Test Connection" link . Neither work, so this is likely the problem. This error message references a Technote [http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21266028] and two exception codes:

**ADMC0017E:** `Could not create an RMI connector to connect to host localhost at port 2809` and **ADMC0016E**: `The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host localhost at port 8880`

I did not see anything helpful in the Technote. Perhaps I have a Windows 7 setting problem?

Comment: John, i am at a loss to explain what is happening. Can you double check the port numbers and ensure that the server is indeed using 2809 and 8880 for RMI and SOAP respectively?

Comment: I did that by going into the Admin Console. Everything looked correct. Since I had been several days without being able to use RAD, I could no longer afford to lose more time. So, I went ahead and uninstalled/reinstalled RAD. Things are working now. Unfortunately, this means I don't know what caused the problem originally or how to avoid or fix it in the future. Thanks again for your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by deleting the server profile "AppSrv1" (Windows -> Preferences -> Servers) and by creating a new one using the profile management tool at the same page.