# Why isn't RAD (Eclipse) able to properly detect WAS server startup?

Tags: java, websphere, rad

If I start WAS 6.1 under RAD 8.0.4.1, I see the server start in the console:

```
[9/24/12 17:21:18:671 EDT] 0000000a WsServerImpl  A   WSVR0001I: Server server1 open for e-business
```

RAD continues to indicate that it's waiting for server startup in the progress pane: "Starting WebSphere Application Server v6.1 at localhost". This is a pain because it eventually times out and tells me the server never started even though it's running and responding to requests and it seems like this state means publishing updates as I change code fails to work.

I don't see any errors in the console during server startup - same for the WebSphere 6.1 Launcher's console.

Is there a simple way to fix this?

Comment: It was answered on this post too.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336112/rad-8-does-not-recognize-that-was-has-started/25066202#25066202

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question I believe has been asked a few times.

Read this technote and see if any of those suggestions help

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21207553

HTH

Comment: thanks. I had a problem finding that link. Turns out it had to do with my proxy settings.